# How to generate one geojson file from several rows in Postgres/PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, geojson

I have a table with geospatial objects, in particular, polygons. I know that I can generate from **one** row a geoJSON string using `ST_AsGeoJSON`(http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsGeoJSON.html). But I would like to *generate* one geoJSON from all the table. Is this possible? How can I do it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you use PostgreSQL 9.2 or higher, you'll find [here](http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/267-Creating-GeoJSON-Feature-Collections-with-JSON-and-PostGIS-functions.html) some explaniations.

Comment: See  this related question to generate GeoJSON using PostGIS http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/76319/what-is-the-most-common-way-of-displaying-geodata-from-postgis-on-leaflet

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Already make a comment but in addition if you choose OGR2OGR, the way to export to GeoJSON is the following:

If you want to keep original SRS

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" yourdataoutputname.geojson PG:"host=localhost user=username dbname=yourdatabasename password=yourpassword" "yourpostgistable"
```

If you want to convert to default SRS for GeoJSON (EPSG 4326)

```
ogr2ogr -f "GeoJSON" yourdataoutputname.geojson -t_srs EPSG:4326 PG:"host=localhost user=username dbname=yourdatabasename password=yourpassword" "yourpostgistable"
```

Answer (score 1):

i think, you need generate row by row with this function ST_AsGeoJSON or export database/table with [org2ogr](http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html)